# Bound on the measure of a sum of sets

Tags: haar-measure, amenability

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group (I am mostly interested in $\mathbb{R}^d$)  with Haar measure $\mu$ be the Haar measure. Consider a fixed compact set $K$ containing the identity. Is it true  that
$$
 f(E) = \mu(E + K) / \mu(E)
$$
is a bounded function for $E$ ranging in the compact sets? it is possible to do this for $E$ ranging in the open sets? I think this has to do with $G$ being amenable.

Edit: The case I am particularly interested is for sequences $f(E)$ when  $E$ is growing to $G$, i.e. $\mu(U) \to \mu(G)$ since I am particularly interested in computing the supremum of such $f$ when $E$ ranges in an increasing Folner sequence.

Comment: It's not true for open sets, if you take $E=\mathbb{Z}\cdot (-1/100,1/100)$ and $K=(-1/2,1/2)$. (This does not rule out the bounded open sets, or bounded sets in general)

Comment: I mean, if $K=[-1,1]$, then $$\mu([0,\varepsilon]+K)/\mu([0,\varepsilon])=\mu([-1, 1+\varepsilon])/\mu([0,\varepsilon])=\frac2\varepsilon+1$$ which is certainly not bounded.

Comment: Thanks I haven't given much thought to the case when $E$ is getting smaller. See the edit.